# R error with formattable "must return compatible vectors across groups"

Tags: r, formattable

I am trying to apply currency formatting to TOTAL in a grouped data frame using formattable. However I get the error: *"`TOTAL`" must return compatible vectors across groups.*

Here's some reproducible code that produces the error:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)

n <- 100
data <- data.frame(
   FY = round(runif(n, 2020, 2025), digits = 0),
   LOBJ = round(runif (n, 1, 10), digits = 0),
   VALUE = rnorm(n, 50, 20)
)

data_summary <- data %>%
   group_by(FY, LOBJ) %>%
   summarize(TOTAL = sum(VALUE)) %>%
   mutate(TOTAL = currency(TOTAL))
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using `summarise()` making a list and then unseating the result.  That will keep the grouping structure and do the right thing with the `currency()` formatting:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(formattable)

n <- 100
data <- data.frame(
  FY = round(runif(n, 2020, 2025), digits = 0),
  LOBJ = round(runif (n, 1, 10), digits = 0),
  VALUE = rnorm(n, 50, 20)
)

data_summary <- data %>%
  group_by(FY, LOBJ) %>% 
  summarise(TOTAL = list(currency(sum(VALUE))), .groups="keep") %>%
  unnest(TOTAL)
data_summary
#> # A tibble: 45 × 3
#> # Groups:   FY, LOBJ [45]
#>       FY  LOBJ TOTAL     
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <formttbl>
#>  1  2020     1 $22.79    
#>  2  2020     3 $28.04    
#>  3  2020     4 $100.87   
#>  4  2020     5 $31.04    
#>  5  2020     6 $98.79    
#>  6  2020     9 $51.16    
#>  7  2021     1 $65.79    
#>  8  2021     2 $56.60    
#>  9  2021     3 $263.45   
#> 10  2021     4 $85.72    
#> # ℹ 35 more rows
```

It also works as you wrote it if you ungroup the data before calling `mutate()`.

```r
data_summary <- data %>%
  group_by(FY, LOBJ) %>%
  summarize(TOTAL = sum(VALUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(TOTAL = currency(TOTAL))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'FY'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
data_summary
#> # A tibble: 45 × 3
#>       FY  LOBJ TOTAL     
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <formttbl>
#>  1  2020     1 $22.79    
#>  2  2020     3 $28.04    
#>  3  2020     4 $100.87   
#>  4  2020     5 $31.04    
#>  5  2020     6 $98.79    
#>  6  2020     9 $51.16    
#>  7  2021     1 $65.79    
#>  8  2021     2 $56.60    
#>  9  2021     3 $263.45   
#> 10  2021     4 $85.72    
#> # ℹ 35 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>